# How to find out the row count in input file using in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Requirement is "I have a text file**(test.txt)**. It contains 5 lines of data.I need to total count of records in test.txt files using sql query in SQL server.

Input: I have a file.It contain data like..
a
b
c
d
e

**Required OUTPUT:**
Count: 5

Answer (score 0):

Removed my earlier answer, because @sepupic was correct. I was too quick and provided a wrong answer. Apologies for that.

Here's what I did. I created a text file, and dropped it in my C:\temp folder. The name of the file is c:\temp\MyText.txt, and it contains a few lines (7) of text.

I then created a table to host the data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTableName
(myText nvarchar(50));
```

Using `BULK INSERT` I then import the contents into my table:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.myTableName
FROM 'c:\temp\MyText.txt'
WITH
(
  CODEPAGE = '1252',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
  CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
)
```

Finally, I perform a rowcount on the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As LineCount FROM dbo.YourTableName
```

This yields the desired result:

```
LineCount
7
```

Contents of the table:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTableName
```

Result:

```
Text
THIS IS A FILE
WITH SEVERAL
LINES 
AND CONTINUING
ON 
A FEW
MORE
```

Comment: This will iether return an error if the file is not unicode, or will return 1 as it reads the file as **SINGLE** row

Comment: Interesting. I'll amend with a possible fix (can't test it at the moment, unfortunately)

Comment: While I am executing this query, I,m getting below error:                          
 Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\miracle1\Desktop\FTP\Get\sample.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). Could you please help me out from these.

Comment: @ SchmitzIT Your code, as long as it uses SINGLE_(BLOB, CLOB, NCLOB), will ALWAYS return 1 if not the error. Single means the whole file will be loaded as a single value

Comment: @Sujay - Sounds like the account SQL server runs under is not allowed to access the file in your profile. Try putting the file somewhere not in your profile?

Comment: HI @SchmitzIT..Thanks for quick response.Actually I'm aware of BULK INSERT process,that is extract from data from file and insert into table,then find the count of records from table. that is fine,actually my requirement is to retrieve the data from table and created a file. once,s placed the data in file ,now I want to get the row count in input data file. Could you please help me on this.Its urgent requirement.

Comment: @SchmitzIT,Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: If you don't want to use BULK INSERT, perhaps an SSIS task would work. Why is BULK INSERT not a good solution?

Comment: @SchmitzIT , Actually in my flow we are getting data from table  and parsed  the data and generated a file in some location. From that file we trying to find the count of records in file. we want the count "how many records in placed in file",that is my task.

Comment: @sujay How is the file generated? I would think that would be the place to intercept the amount of rows delivered.